# Handling conditional classnames that do not return anything

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component (that has been simplified for this post) that looks like this:

```
const CoinSymbol = ({ classes, symbol }) => (
  <i className={[symbol, 'cc'].join(' ')} />
)
```

The 'cc' + symbol will create a valid classname that the library will use to return a webfont icon.

I am calling it on a map() function like this:

`<CoinSymbol symbol={coin.symbol} />`

A lot of the symbols do get displayed, but there are some symbols that do not exist in the library. React will render the element to the DOM, but obviously does not display anything on the page because it is not a valid className.

I would like to solve for the missing icons, but am not too sure on how to approach it. My current plan is to render a (?) icon in place of the missing icons.

What would be a good approach at handling such a case?

Answer (score 0):

This is more of a CSS question than a JS question, so it would be good to see the CSS used for rendering.

But in general, a common approach would be to define a default icon that loads for *all* your icon components, but then if the symbol actually exists, that will override the default.

```css
/* Default / fallback */
i.cc {
  background: url("/icons/coins/unknown.png");
}

/* Valid symbols override the default */
i.cc.eth {
  background: url("/icons/coins/eth.png");
}
```